# Regular expression to match from the end of a match condition

Tags: regex, preg-match

I want to match from the end of a result from a or condition in **regular expression**.

```
$a = 'SI-#CL#¤1801 BARBER LANE#CL#MILPITAS CA 95035#CL#FONE 1-408-943-0600#CL#FAX 1-408-943-0484#CL#¤CANCEL BY 5 PM - RQST-NO FEATHER';
$pat = '/^(?(?=SI)(?<matchfromend>[A-Z]+$)|(?<else>.*))/';
```

i want to match **CANCEL BY 5 PM - RQST-NO FEATHER** only if string starts from **SI-**

Any suggestion ??

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to match?

Comment: i want to match CANCEL BY 5 PM - RQST-NO FEATHER only if string starts from SI-

Comment: Another idea with conditional: [`^(?(?=SI-).*#¤)\K.+`](https://regex101.com/r/pR7rN6/3) or [one without](https://regex101.com/r/pR7rN6/1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `(?(?=SI)(?<matchfromend>[A-Z]+$)` regex part does not consume arbitrary characters from the beginning of the string up to the end `(?<matchfromend>[A-Z]+$` pattern.

You can use the following regex:

```
'~^(?(?=SI).*#¤(?<matchfromend>.+$)$|(?<else>.*))~'
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bI1aO9/1)

*Explanation*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?(?=SI).*#¤(?<matchfromend>.+$)$|(?<else>.*))` - a conditional:

  - If `SI` appears at the start (`(?=SI)`) match 0+ characters other than a newline up to the last `#¤`, and capture 1+ characters other than a newline up to the end of the string into Group "matchfromend"
  - If there is no `SI` at the start, match 0+ characters other than a newline up to the end of the line.

**Another NON-REGEX approach**

Check if a string starts with `SI` and if yes, explode with `#¤` and get the last item. If not, use the whole string.

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/80N6Zd):

```
$str = "SI-#CL#¤1801 BARBER LANE#CL#MILPITAS CA 95035#CL#FONE 1-408-943-0600#CL#FAX 1-408-943-0484#CL#¤CANCEL BY 5 PM - RQST-NO FEATHER"; // => CANCEL BY 5 PM - RQST-NO FEATHER
//$str = "#CL#¤1801 BARBER LANE#CL#MILPITAS CA 95035#CL#FONE 1-408-943-0600#CL#FAX 1-408-943-0484#CL#¤CANCEL BY 5 PM - RQST-NO FEATHER"; 
$res = $str;
if (strrpos($str, "SI", -strlen($str)) !== false) { // starts with SI
    $arr = explode("#¤", $str);
    if (!empty($arr)){
        $res  = array_pop($arr);
    }
}
echo $res;
```

Comment: I think a conditional is enough, please check (no need capturing inside a lookahead) .